# How can you add a serialize method to a class member that is a Windows data struct for use with boost serialization in C++

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have searched the web and can't seem to find a clear answer on this matter. Basically, I have a class with some members that are Windows defined data structs. For example, SYSTEMTIME is the type of one of the members. I have added the serialize method, etc. to the class definition per the boost documentation. It compiles fine without the more complex Windows data types (e.g. BOOL, primitives, etc work fine). If I add them, I receive an error message like "... serialize is not a member of SYSTEMTIME ...". I tried the "unobtrusive" serialization method where a SYSTEMTIME parameter is passed. I even tried redefining the whole struct with the added serialization method. In that case, I received a redefinition error.

I understand that members of class or struct type need their own serialization method and how it is called when the containing class' serialization method is called, but just can't seem to figure out how to do this for types that I did not define. I am new to boost and I am a little lost here, any help on the subject would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1:

I think I was referring to non-obtrusive as I wasn't aware that there was a difference. I first tried adding:

```
    namespace boost {
        namespace serialization {
            template<typename Archive>
            void serialize( Archive& ar, SYSTEMTIME& st, const unsigned int version ) {
                ar & st.wYear;
                ar & st.wMonth;
                ar & st.wDayOfWeek;
                ar & st.wDay;
                ar & st.wHour;
                ar & st.wMinute;
                ar & st.wSecond;
                ar & st.wMilliseconds;
            }
        }
    }
```

and received the error serialization is not a member of _SYSTEMTIME. I just tried it again and it compiled, h'mmm, I will test to see if it works and post again.

Comment: I would follow the non-intrusive (I think this fits better than "unobtrusive", but I had to look up the meanings to know the difference!  Incidentally, I think you might the describe the non intrusive approach slightly obtrusive, as you have to add a global overload of the serialize method...) approach, myself.  Can you post the error message you got when you attempted this?

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for your quick response. I think I was referring to non-obtrusive as I wasn't aware that there was a difference. I first tried adding:

Comment: @Aaron sorry the comment cut me off, I edited the post above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't tell what you did "wrong", but here's proof that it works.

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f41b07c1d0912db2)**

With the output

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -Os -Wall -pedantic main.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_serialization && ./a.out
22 serialization::archive 10 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Code:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

typedef uint32_t WORD;

typedef struct _SYSTEMTIME {
    WORD wYear;
    WORD wMonth;
    WORD wDayOfWeek;
    WORD wDay;
    WORD wHour;
    WORD wMinute;
    WORD wSecond;
    WORD wMilliseconds;
} SYSTEMTIME, *PSYSTEMTIME;

namespace boost { namespace serialization {
    template<typename Archive>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, SYSTEMTIME& st, const unsigned int version) {
            ar & st.wYear;
            ar & st.wMonth;
            ar & st.wDayOfWeek;
            ar & st.wDay;
            ar & st.wHour;
            ar & st.wMinute;
            ar & st.wSecond;
            ar & st.wMilliseconds;
        }
} }

int main()
{
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);
    SYSTEMTIME d { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
    oa << d;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for testing that. I believe the problem was that I had made the SYSTEMTIME parameter a const initially (I think I saw an example somewhere that did it that way ... ). Once removed, it compiled.

Comment: @Paul yeah, that would be a problem. You **can** have it const for output serialization with [`BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(SYSTEMTIME)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#splitting), see that link :)

Comment: Cool, thanks! I am still a little bit confused on how to do this in the context of a class (e.g. SYSTEMTIME as a member type). Would I just do what I did, but also for the class, too? Adding something like `code`namespace boost {...same code as above...serialize( Archive& ar, ClassName& obj, const unsigned int version ) ar & SYSTEMTIME membername; ar & other members...}`code` and the SYSTEMTIME member will then refer to the separate serialization method when called ... ?

Comment: @Paul Simply: yes. I might add that you're free to use "intrusive" (member) style _serialization hooks_ if you please. It's no problem to mix and match.